# is it possible to loop faster than the minimal time for setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node js script that sends https requests and loops through a large list of strings in a text document. The problem is that this takes a long time to perform on all of them. I would like to be able to perform this task faster.

This is the code

```js
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');
const ids = fs.readFileSync('./list.txt', 'utf-8').split('\n');

let count = 0;

let i = 0;
let a = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        const id = ids[i].trim();
        request.get(`https://websitethingy.com/endpoint/${id}`, {
            headers: {
                "User-Agent": "Android/126021",
                "Authorization": "auth_token"
            },
            body: ``
        }, (err, res, body) => {
            if (!err && res.statusCode == 404) {
                console.log("not found", id);
            }
            console.log(body);
            count += 1;
            process.title = `[total requests: ${count}]`;
        });
        ++i;
        if(i === ids.length) i = 0;
    }, 1);
}
a();
```

This loops through the entire list at every millisecond which performs at about 900-ish requests per second and I can't seem to find a faster way to perform this task.

Comment: Why use `setInterval()` to begin with?

Comment: Drop the `setInterval`, just do the loop.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate

Comment: @Teemu `seImmediate` do the same as `setTimeout` without a second argument

Comment: @Konrad Well, practically yes, but in theory it creates a timer with zero delay.

Comment: loop over `ids` with `for...of` or `forEach`, `map` kind of loops and deal with the results asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

You can do loop faster just with `.forEach` looping.

---

**Node.js**

```js
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');
let ids = fs.readFileSync('./list.txt', 'utf-8').split('\n');

let count = 0;

ids.forEach((id, i) => {
    request.get(`https://websitethingy.com/endpoint/${id.trim()}`, {
        headers: {
            "User-Agent": "Android/126021",
            "Authorization": "auth_token"
        },
        body: ``
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        if (!err && res.statusCode == 404) {
            console.log("not found", id);
        }
        console.log(body);
        count += 1;
        // process.title = `[total requests: ${count}]`;
        console.log(`[total requests: ${count}]`);
    });
});
```

---

**Vanila JS**

```js
let count = 0;
let ids = [...Array(20).keys()].slice(1); // [0, 1, ..., 19]
ids.forEach((id) => {
    fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/products/${id}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((body) => {
        console.log(body);
        count++;
        console.log(`[total requests: ${count}]`);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("not found", id);
        console.error(err);
    });
});
```